# cannot read property of 'channels' of undefined discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```js
const reason = args.slice(0).join(" ");
    if (!reason) return message.channel.send('Reason for ticket?');
const user =  message.guild.member(message.author);
 const ticket = db.fetch(`Ticket_user_${user.id}`)
if(ticket) message.channel.send("You already made a ticket senpai! Close your old ticket.");
 const channel = message.guild.channels.cache.find
        (channel => channel.name === 'ticket')
      if (!channel)
guild.channels.create('ticket', {
    type: 'text',
    permissionOverwrites: [
        {
            id: message.guild.id,
            deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
        },
        {
            id: message.author.id,
            allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
        },
    ],
})
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(err => {
   message.channel.send("An error occurred while running the command. Please report this error to the support server:"+ err)
  return;
})
 db.add(`Ticket_user_${user.id}`)
const time = "3"
 setTimeout(() => {
   const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(`Ticket#0001`)
      .setDescription(`Reason: ${reason}`)
      .addField("Welcome to my ticket senpai!! We are waiting for staff")
      .setColor("PURPLE")
message.channel.send(embed)
    }, ms(time))
}
}
```

I'm making a ticket system for my bot and ik you people smart because top.gg won't help
Thank you for the help this will help my bot and my code and make me smart plus I'm removing the dot becccause of downvote ig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in this code

```js
if (!channel){
    guild.channels.create('ticket', { //...... rest of the code
```

You didn't define `guild`. Try replacing `guild` with `message.guild`
Like this:

```js
if (!channel){
message.guild.channels.create('ticket', { //.... rest of the code
```

Also, please remove the unnecessary part (dots) from the question